# Nodejs sharing same initiated class to sub routes

Tags: node.js, class, inheritance, subclass

I have a folder structer like this

```
.
├── models
│   └── System.js
└── src
    ├── app.js
    ├── index.js
    └── routes
        ├── lemon
        │   ├── auth
        │   │   └── index.js
        │   └── index.js
        └── index.js
```

.

**/models/System.js**

```
class System {
    constructor() {
        this.test = null;
    }
}

module.exports = System
```

.

**/src/app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const _System = require("../models/System");

const app = express();

var System = new _System();
System.test = 1;

//..... other codes
```

.

**/src/routes/lemon/auth/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const _System = require("../../../../models/System");

const router = express.Router();

console.log(_System.test); //returns null

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World");
});

module.exports = router;
```

.

My folder structer is like this and I'm trying to share the **System.test = 1** value defined at */app.js* to */routes/lemon/auth/index.js*.
But I couldn't able to do that and it always return null.

Is there anyway to share the same class init to sub routes?

*PS: I know that my code isn't right and I've searched a lot. I can't understand English resources too much at the moment but I really searched up for it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant or scalable but;

```
global.System =  new _System();
```

You can then use `System` anywhere.

Comment: Till I found a more good solution, your solution is the best! Thanks @RussFreeman

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt work because `System.js` returns a class and not an instance or an object. So when `var System = new _System(); System.test = 1;` is exectued in `app.js`, the instance is local to the app module and not shared with the route.

If you want to share some kind of a config file between different modules, you can define your `System` module as a simple object:

```js
'use strict' // <-- this is good practice to be more rigoreous

const System = {
    test: 1
};

module.exports = System;
```

Comment: The **test** variable is just an example. What I need to do is, use the **System=new _System()** anywhere. Once I initiated the **System**, I'll need able to use it in the deepest route file